# Automatically Size DataGridView(s) within UserControl Based on Row Count

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, user-controls

I created a usercontrol which contains some heading labels and a datagridview. I insert this usercontrol onto form1 n number of times depending on the rowcount returned from a SQL query. The number of rows in each datagrid is then determined also by another SQL query. I want to automatically size the usercontrols (and their inner datagridviews) to match the number of rows in each datagridview, so that when I add them on my form they are spaced accordingly and all of the data can be viewed, without gaps in between each usercontrol that are too large or too small.

Below is what I tried and a screenshot of the result, which currently doesn't seem to be sized appropriately. I cannot share the SQL query but I can tell you that from debugging, both w and q variables are populating as expected.

```
 int w = distinctValues.Rows.Count;
        int y = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
        {
            String value = distinctValues.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL QUERY HERE, CANT SHARE DUE TO CONFIDENTIALITY);
            DataTable datatable2 = new DataTable();
            adapter2.Fill(datatable2);
            int q = datatable2.Rows.Count;
                var UC = new UCEPMS();
                UC.Name = "UC1" + i;
                UC.Width = 2480;
            UC.Height = (42 * q) + 20;
            UC.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, y);
                panel1.Controls.Add(UC);
                UC.Show();
                int UCAnchor = UC.Bottom;
                y = UCAnchor+ 20;
            datatable2.Rows.Clear();
        }
```

[Here is my bad result. On some examples where the rowcount is much higher, the gap is much greater, which makes sense given my code. I know I am not taking the right approach, but am unclear on how to achieve my desired visual.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abh1w.png)

Comment: And you can’t use a `FlowLayoutPanel`? like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299704/how-can-i-get-a-stackpanel-like-layout-in-winforms

Comment: @RandRandom Assuming I do this and add the user controls within the FlowLayoutPanel programmatically, won't I still have to set the user control height?

Comment: well if you anchored your controls no: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623746/auto-size-the-controls-in-winform - some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59928704/how-to-make-a-winforms-app-perspective-and-responsive-like-a-web-page - documentation about layouting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/layout?view=netdesktop-7.0

Comment: @RandRandom You're right, it worked well I appreciate the suggestions and documentation

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the flowLayoutPanel as @RandRandom suggested, I also found the underlying issue. I was not setting the dataGridView height accordingly, only the height of the user control. I modified my code to the following:

```
int w = distinctValues.Rows.Count;
    int y = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
    {
        String value = distinctValues.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL QUERY HERE, CANT SHARE DUE TO CONFIDENTIALITY);
        DataTable datatable2 = new DataTable();
        adapter2.Fill(datatable2);
        int q = datatable2.Rows.Count;
            var UC = new UCEPMS();
            UC.Name = "UC1" + i;
            UC.Width = 2480;
        UC.Height = (42 * q) + 20;
        UC.dgvHeight = UC.Height - 20;
        UC.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, y);
            panel1.Controls.Add(UC);
            UC.Show();
            int UCAnchor = UC.Bottom;
            y = UCAnchor+ 20;
        datatable2.Rows.Clear();
    }
```

And in my user control:

```
 public int dgvHeight
        {
        get
        {
            return dataGridView1.Height;
        }
        set
        {
            dataGridView1.Height = value;
        }
    
        }
```